# Необходимо преобразовать тест в список слов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Из текста необходимо вычленить все слова и добавить в список без знаков препинания.

Пример:
У нас имеется такой текст: 'От города до дачи полчаса езды. Я то и дело поглядывала по сторонам, но ничего подозрительного узреть 
не смогла и вскоре успокоилась. Затем я увидела чудо.'

Должен получиться список слов ['От', 'города', 'до' ...]

Comment: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string

text = 'От города до дачи полчаса езды ... Затем я увидела чудо.'
words = text.translate({ord(c): None for c in string.punctuation}).split()
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение через регулярные выражения:

```
import re

text = 'От города до дачи полчаса езды. Я то и дело поглядывала по сторонам, но ничего подозрительного узреть не смогла и вскоре успокоилась. Затем я увидела чудо.'
words = re.findall('\w+', text)
print(words)  # ['От', 'города', 'до', 'дачи', 'полчаса', 'езды', ...
```